# How do I get my image to go in the center of the div?

Tags: css, layout, html

Given this HTML:

```
<div>
  <img id="image">
</div>
```

How do I get the image to go in the center of the div?

At the moment it is located in the top left of the div.

I tried

```
img#image
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

But it made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving position `relative` to div:

```
#div_id{
  position:relative;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}
```

and this CSS for image:

```
#img_id{
  position:absolute;
  top:100px; /* half of parent div's height */
  left:200px;  /* half of parent div's width */
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the text-align on the container like:

```
<div class="image">
  <img />
</div>    

div.image {
   text-align: center;
}
```

More info here: 
http://www.gtalbot.org/NvuSection/NvuWebDesignTips/HorizontalAlignment.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<img style='display:block; margin:0 auto' src='...'>
```

Will center the image within its container

Comment: That centers the image on the horizontal axis but not vertically in the div. When I apply this, the image appears in the top center position of the div.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
div { text-align: center; }
#image { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
```